# How do I modify my Quick Sort Algorithm so that it can sort Double data type arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I used this Quick Sort algorithm to sort arrays of integers but I also want it to sort arrays of doubles. Which variables do I need to change to make this work? I tried changing many different combinations of data types.

Any help is appreciated.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {

     double[] myArray_3 = { 25.1573, 5.1437, 8.1421, 3.1625, 12.3187, 2.8465, 78.0454, -32.6666, -
     51.9204, -31.9391, -30.6136, -12.1411, -4.7172, -6.1189, 15.1574, 10.8995, 21.0344, 49.7912};
     double[] myArray_4 = {-56.6149, -27.4997, 17.1503, -1.5368, -31.3245, -17.5386, 6.9865, -27.8045,
     27.2986, -17.9399, 50.6482, -30.2363, 5.5773, -42.5887, -20.2617, -16.6110, 11.2374,
     26.3797, 8.4136, -10.4460, 22.8337, 22.3688, 3.3657, 15.9949, 11.5583, -27.6349, 21.2679, -
     18.4016, -16.9097, 4.9545, -8.6101, -3.6910};

        QuickSort(myArray_3);

        foreach (int item in myArray_3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
    public static void QuickSort(int[] data)
    {
        Quick_Sort(data, 0, data.Length - 1);
    }

    public static void Quick_Sort(int[] data, int left, int right)
    {
        int i, j;
        int pivot, temp;
        i = left;
        j = right;
        pivot = data[(left + right) / 2];
        do
        {
            while ((data[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
            while ((pivot < data[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i <= j);
        if (left < j) Quick_Sort(data, left, j);
        if (i < right) Quick_Sort(data, i, right);
    }
```

Comment: You might consider making `Quick_Sort()` a generic method with the type constraint of `IComparable<>`. e.g. `public static void Quick_Sort<T>(T[] data, int left, int right) where T : IComparable<T> { ... }` Then you can use `data[i].CompareTo(pivot)` or whatever instead of `<` and `>` operators. ints and doubles both implement `IComparable<>`, so it will work for both of those, plus anything else that implements that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use generics, where the type implements `IComparable<T>`, so that you can compare the items (you can't use `<` or `>` operators on generic types).

This should do the trick:

```
public static void QuickSort<T>(T[] data) where T:IComparable<T>
{
    Quick_Sort(data, 0, data.Length - 1);
}

public static void Quick_Sort<T>(T[] data, int left, int right) where T:IComparable<T>
{
    int i, j;
    T pivot, temp;
    i = left;
    j = right;
    pivot = data[(left + right) / 2];

    do
    {
        while ((data[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0) && (i < right)) i++;
        while ((pivot.CompareTo(data[j]) < 0) && (j > left)) j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (left < j) Quick_Sort(data, left, j);
    if (i < right) Quick_Sort(data, i, right);
}
```

Comment: And I see that itsme86 basically wrote the answer freehand in the comments in less time than I could modify your code in Visual Studio. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem  ^^ It is sorting properly but now It doesn't display the numbers with their decimal values, how can I print out the array of numbers with all of the 4 decimal places? (Yes, I'm a noob).

Comment: Well, in your `foreach` code you're casting all the items from `double` to `int`. Don't do that. :)  It should be: `foreach (double item in myArray_3)`

Comment: *Facepalm* Haha I make such silly mistakes... Thanks again

Comment: The equal operator is not as straightforward with doubles. You need to compare against the floating point epsilon.

Comment: @partycoder: that's not relevant because we aren't doing any equality checks here...

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you decide to go with:

---

**Using floating point numbers safely**

The reliable way to define equality for double precision floating point numbers is not `operator==`. It is:

`(a - b < Double.Epsilon)`

---

**On Quicksort specifically**

Quicksort looks simple at first but has many gotchas. First one is that it has worst case performance that can be quadratic. If you want to roll your own quicksort you need to be aware of how to mitigate those cases:

1. Shuffle the array prior to sorting. This is required to guarantee  performance. Specifically, Hoare partition scheme, the original partitioning scheme for quicksort, has degraded performance if the array presents certain orderings.
2. Remember that Quicksort is not a stable sorting algorithm. Meaning that  you cannot sort by more than one criteria because the order is not preserved across nested sorts.
3. The Dutch national flag problem. If you allow duplicate values, you can end up with a fat partition which would make quicksort run in quadratic time (`O(n^2)`). This can be solved through quicksort variants like 3-way quicksort.

Comment: epsilon concerns are inappropriate here. We absolutely **do** want strict comparison between our values when *sorting*. We *want* epsilon, 2*epsilon, 3*epsilon to all be considered *different*.

Comment: @AakashM: More importantly quality concerns are inappropriate here because when sorting we always use comparisons, not equality checks. Also the content of this answer while possibly interesting for those wanting to know more about quicksort are not relevant to the question which was how can I convert this to sort doubles instead of integers.

Comment: That's in case you want to do an exact comparison at some point, but sure, point granted. Inequality operators are fine. Just have in mind that when dealing with floating point numbers anyways, there's no harm :)

Comment: @partycoder thank you for mentioning about shuffling the array first. The arrays I have to work with have quite a lot of ordering, for example 20 elements of the same name in order. But how does one shuffle the array? I've also read that another way is to choose a random pivot to minimize the worst case performance but can't find any examples of how that is done

Comment: @IllimarIssak you can use a Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth shuffle) implementation which has time complexity `O(n)`